# Can I save only certain fields from a syslog with rsyslogd?

Tags: debian, syslog, rsyslog

I'm using rsyslogd to receive logs via UDP.

There are many fields inside each row of logs saved (separated with a pipe | ) and I was wondering if there is any way to configure rsyslog to only save 2-3 fields out of the ~20 fields that are received.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a [property replacer](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/property_replacer.html), of which perhaps the simplest in this case is the field split. For example, `%msg:F,45:1%` selects field 1 (the first) of the `msg` property after a split on character code decimal 45, which is `-`.

The `|` symbol is ascii code 0x7c which is decimal 124. Fields are numbered from 1. If you want several fields, you need to repeat the replacer for each. You would also need to put back the `|` separator.

Use this in a template. For example, if you are using `RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat` and want fields 3 and 7, then create your own:

```
template(name="mytemplate" type="string"
   string="%TIMESTAMP% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag% %msg:F,124:3%|%msg:F,124:7%\n")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @meuh, I will give it a try!